# SwiftyJson do not parse from NSBundle

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I have a big Json data inside a file in my storage and I'm trying to parse that json using SwiftyJson . this is my code :

```
  let path  = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ostan_city", ofType: "JSON")!
            do {
                let jsonDta = try NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
                let json = JSON(data: jsonDta)
                for item in json["ostan"].arrayValue {
                    var citiesArray = [city]()
                    for cities in item["cities"].arrayValue {
                        citiesArray.append(city(id: cities["id"].stringValue , name: cities["name"].stringValue ))
                    }
                    ostans.append(ostan(id: item["id"].stringValue, name: item["name"].stringValue , cities: citiesArray) )
                    citiesArray = []
                }

            }catch {

            }
```

I've debugged it and the path and jsonDta both have values but after JSON method runs, It has no value inside it and swiftyJson returns nothing .

What's the problem ?
Is it the right way of getting json from nsbundle ?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you use URLForResource?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no problem. The problem is in your ostan_city.JSON, it is not in JSON format.

Comment: This is a comment, i.e. not an answer.